# Error inflating class selector when using an image selector in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, selector

I'm using a GridView and an image selector so that my image is different when it's pressed vs when it's not pressed. Everything compiles, but when I run the application I get an error " Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class selector".

Is it possible to use an image selector inside a gridview? When I take the selector out of the xml, it runs fine.

Here's the xml for each grid item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >
<selector   
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/status_button_down"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/status_button_down"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/status_button_up" />
</selector>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status"    
        android:textSize="9pt"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textColor="#000000"  
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the code for the adapter for the grid view:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    //return mThumbIds.length;
    return 16;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;
        //ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

        gridView = new View(mContext);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.drawable.status_button, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

        textView.setText("Status");


    } else {
        //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        gridView = (View) convertView;

    }

    return gridView;

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector should actually be set in your "drawables" folder as its own .xml file.  Then you can call it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/my_selector" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >
```

Comment: Thanks, I did that and added some extra space to the bottom of the images and it worked. I also had to add some extra spaces to the beginning of the text in order to get it to be center aligned, even though I specified center_horizontal. If you know of a better way to do it then adding spaces let me know.

Comment: Well your TextView width says, "wrap_content" which means centering it will do nothing since your TextView will always be (basically) the same size as your text.  You will need to set it to "fill_parent" or "match_parent" (depending on api) in order to get it to do what you want.